# Performance impact of function calls in an SQL Query (About Context Switching)

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, database-performance, context-switching

Are there any performance impact in calling functions in an SQL statement due to context switching between SQL and PL/SQL engines? Or is the potential impact dependent on the function called?

1. Calling built-in functions:

```
select dbms_crypto.hash(utl_raw.cast_to_raw(COLUMN),1) from TABLE_NM;
```

2. Calling PL/SQL functions:

```
create or replace package PCK as
  function doSomething(val varchar2) return varchar2;
end PCK;

select PCK.doSomething(COLUMN) from TABLE_NM
```

Are there performance overhead due to function calls? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Calling built-in functions:

It depends. But, most of the **native SQL functions** and **built-in functions** are compiled in low-level "**C language**" as a single module in the **Oracle kernel**. For example, `CASE` or `UPPER` function won't have any **context switch** between the two engines as I said they are in a single module.

Well, there are some built-in functions which are exceptions, like `SYSDATE` and `USER` etc. **Thomas Kyte** has beautifully explained it [here](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::p11_question_id:60122715103602).

> Calling PL/SQL functions

A **SQL call in PL/SQL**, or vice-versa, i.e. a **PL/SQL call in SQL** needs a **context switch**. There is a call overhead to go from SQL to PLSQL (the "hit" is most evident when SQL invokes PLSQL - not so much the other way, when SQL is embedded in PLSQL).